# How to recover constant / intercept from a model when using fixest / feols()?

Tags: r, data-modeling, modeling

So I have a model I estimated using `feols()` from the `fixest` package. I have to extract all coefficients and export them to a different program to calculate the predicted values for other observations (not in R). For this I used the following code:

```
model.coef <- c(unlist(fixef(my_model)), coef(my_model))
```

I then saved and exported my results. However, I have noticed that neither `coef()` or `fixef()` extract the model's constant. I also know that there must be a constant as all my factor variables are missing one (the first) level and similarly for my fixed effects, each one is missing one level. Hence, I was wondering if there is a way to recover the value of this constant. I tried doing something like:

```
predict(my_model, newdata = data.frame(
   "var1" = 0, "var2" = 0,
   "factor1" = factor(0), ..., "result_var" = NA)
)
```

However this too cumbersome and it doesn't even work! Since I get the following error:

```
  Error when creating the linear matrix: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I would like to know how can I recover the model's constant, I have found nothing so far looking through `fixest` documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem, the model does not have a constant and the reason why I had less fixed effects than levels was because exactly one of them always had `NA` in an independent variable giving the illusion that one level was omitted. That's the same reason why I was getting that error, since I inputted the fixed effect not included in the model. I will leave this post in case some else has this problem in the future.